# Can I speed up insertion into SQL Server while using INSERT INTO statements with ADO.net

Tags: ado.net, isolation-level, sqlclient

I'm looking to see if there's something I can do to dramatically speed ADO.net insertion, but still do the insertion with multiple `INSERT INTO table values (...)` commands.  I am staging data from proprietary, non-queryable, database files into SQL Server.  The utility I am writing will be used from a script.

I realize that for the best possible performance, `INSERT INTO` is the wrong route to pursue, but I'd still like to know if there's some ADO.net or SQL Server approach I should try.

I'm connecting to SQL Server 2008 using C# 2010. I'm comparing my performance to non-managed code inserting data into SQL Server using Microsoft's ODBC 3.5 driver with Native Client 10.0. Is it reasonable to expect to be able to match ODBC's performance?

The destination table has no indices or other constraints, triggers, it's just a staging table. The source data is a bunch of non-standard datatypes that I have to massage into strings.

Stripped to the relevant detail, my code is:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlTransaction insertTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
comm.Connection = conn;
comm.Transaction = insertTransaction;

while(buffer.ReadNext())  // fill a buffer that I use to make my query
{
    // form my insert statement and assign it
    // It looks like: INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (5,'2016-02-16',NULL,3)
    // A good fraction of the data is numeric with decimal points. A good
    // fraction is dates.  The parsing and string building,
// extravagantly inefficient as it is, is not the culprit.
    // The  INSERT INTO does not specify the column names

    comm.CommandText = myStatement;
    if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1) {throw...}
}

insertTransaction.commit;
```

I've tried specifying different isolation levels; I wasn't able to specify `.Snapshot` (don't want to configure the target database to allow it). Nothing made much difference.

If I comment out `comm.ExecuteNoQuery` to let it just spin through forming the INSERT statments,it goes about as fast as I think it should if it were actually doing something. If I uncomment it, it takes about 8 times longer than I think it should take. "Where does '8 times longer' come from?" you ask.  Well, I do a similar operation (end-to-end identical operation) with Pervasive Data Integrator (ye olde Data Junction). From diagnostics when Pervasive crashes, I believe that program is doing inserts using consecutive `INSERT INTO`
statements, like I am.  It goes about 8 times faster than my program, just a very small amount slower than forming my `INSERT INTO` statements takes if I don't execute them.

Pervasive Integrator is adding thru ODBC, and the ODBC driver is set to use Sql Native client. And Data Integrator is not .Net software. I haven't actually tried going thru
ODBC, I guess I will try it now that it occurs to me, but my goal is to get rid of ODBC so it's just a datapoint, not a solution, even if it's faster.

I have tried populating a dataTable with the intent of doing bulk insert, but populating the dataset took too long, also.  I assume that some alternative way that uses bulk insert is the very fastest way to make it work, but even if I ultimately stop using my `INSERT INTO` approach, I'm curious why it takes so much longer (than I think it should)

The insert statements are fairly long, there are ~350 columns in my table.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried grouping your insert values together into something as simple:

```
INSERT INTO myTables VALUES (5,'2016-02-16',NULL,3), (6,'2015-02-16',NULL,6), (7,'2012-02-16',NULL,6)...
```

Here's a simple implementation, it's not elegant (as well as it's untested and I wrote this in notepad, so there are more than likely typos), but...

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlTransaction insertTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
comm.Connection = conn;
comm.Transaction = insertTransaction;

String baseQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ";

List<String> values = new List<String>();

Int32 i = 0;

while(buffer.ReadNext())  // fill a buffer that I use to make my query
{
    // Build your VALUES section here
    values.Add("(5,'2016-02-16',NULL,3)");

    if (i % 100 == 0)  // Chunk these every 100
    {
        myStatement = baseQuery + String.Join(", ", values.ToArray());

        comm.CommandText = myStatement;

        if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1) {throw...}

        insertTransaction.commit;

        values = new List<String>();  // Clear out our values and start a new
    }

    i++;
}

if (values.Count > 0)  // If any are left, INSERT them
{
    myStatement = baseQuery + String.Join(", ", values.ToArray());

    comm.CommandText = myStatement;

   if (comm.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1) {throw...}

   insertTransaction.commit;
}
```

Comment: I had an boss once who'd say "Don't feel sorry for the bytes" but I was already feeling sorry for my bytes when I was just putting in one 300 column table at a time... so, no, I haven't tried, good idea, I'll report back shortly.  Thanks

Comment: The results are really surprising.  It gets WORSE as you chunk up more stuff.  I'm measuring with clock-on-the-wall time on a shared server, completely unscientific, but some samples to add 1000 records: 1 at a time 11 sec; 2 or 10 at at time, 26 seconds (no consistent difference); 50 at a time 130 seconds.  +1 on the suggestion though, sounded like a winner.  My INSERT INTO statements are about 1,800 chars long each, I wonder if dealing with long text is a problem or if there's any settings to tune for that usage.

Comment: Try this for austerity (assuming you can delete your results).  Generate the results of 1000 traditional INSERTS.
Generate the results of 1000 batched INSERTS.  Run each on the SQL server and time it. Let me know the results. Thanks!

Comment: What are the hardware specs? You may be running into hard limits of network bandwidth and memory allocation.

Comment: You are probably running into buffer limits in SQL.  A 326 field wide row is pretty big for SQL.  I'm sure this is tunable, but blindly throwing switches on a VM you don't know much about is hardly my ideal way of tuning.  Did you try isolating the queries (out of code) and executing directly on the server as I suggested above?  I'm curious if the .net SQL driver is the culprit.

Comment: [I deleted a couple comments since SO was bugging me about extended discussion.]  I hadn't understood your suggestion before.  Wasn't familiar with mechanics of Batches. I pasted a 200 row insert into SSMS, and put one "GO" at the end. 103-119 seconds.  And I pasted in 4 Inserts with 50 rows each, and one "GO" at the end.  And that takes 20 seconds.  50 insert statments, one GO: 0 seconds (that's the performance I want to scale :).  1200 individual inserts, one GO: 3 seconds.  So that's roughly like what I'm seeing in ADO, except that one at a time is a lot faster.

Comment: Sorry. Looks like a tuning opportunity.  One at a time may be your only option unless you can tune SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the data come in one row at a time? In other words, do you have users enter the data into the application and press a button to initiate the insert?
   OR
2. Is all the data readily available for insert?

If (1.) just do an INSERT INTO the way you've been doing.

I'm against accumulating data that comes in one row at a time on the application/client side. This leads to a lot of problems.

If (2.) do a bulk import.

There are 3 types of Bulk Import and Bulk Export operations
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx

Are these files in text format?
Are they columnar?
Are they accessible from the file system (i.e. C:\pathTo\file.ext)?
If yes, generate a bcp format file (print it out from your program, taking care to 
include C:\pathTo\file.ext).
Then TRUNCATE the staging table (or TRUNCATE INTO in the format file generated above) and call the bcp utility via a system() call given the format file and database connection as parameters.
It's super fast.
A direct bcp upload will beat anything you can upload via ado.net.

Comment: I will edit my post to mention this is a non interactive application. It reads from unchanging proprietary database files and writes (a representation of) those files into SQL Server.